# JavaFX Eclipse Error Configure Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, buildpath

I started studying **JavaFX** few days ago and I'm aware that you need the latest version of Java JRE and JDK (both to be sure) to use it. 
I created a new project and tried to follow the tutorials of Bucky Roberts (for basics only) and it works but when I created a **new project** for my Pizza System this **error** pops up in which it didn't show up on my first try of creating a JavaFX program.

[image]

and this is the JavaFX library I created with **jars** from **jre** and **jdk**.

[image]

Comment: you need to import `import javafx.application.Application;` (you have the wrong import ... com.sun....)

Comment: and you don't have to make your own JavaFX library. just add a jre System Library (Add Library -> JRE System Library -> [choose a library])